# Instabot won't download_photo()

Tags: python

So I want to make a script (just for fun) that downloads all the pictures of a given user (that has accepted my follow request of course).. It says "downloading photo:" at some point but then it breaks.. here is the code :

```
bot = instabot.Bot()
bot.min_likes_to_like = 0
bot.max_likes_to_like = 1e3

username = instabot_settings.USERNAME
password = instabot_settings.PASSWORD

if bot.login(username=username, password=password):
    # main script
    user_name = input("Enter someones username to get their photos")
    user_id = bot.get_user_id_from_username(user_name)
    user_medias = bot.get_user_medias(user_id)
    
    os.mkdir(user_name + '_photos')
    
    for media in user_medias:
        post = media.split('_')[0]
        bot.download_photo(post , user_name + '_photos')
```

Any ideas what is going on ?
-Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the error message

Comment: actually there is no error message.. the file is just never downloaded after the execution..